# Wake-on-LAN from internet via IPv6

Tags: networking, router, vpn, ipv6, wake-on-lan

[Moving this from Network Engineering, since it's a home networking question.] I'm a bit new to this, so I'll try to ask my question as coherently as possible.

I'm trying to set up a computer so that I can access it via RDP while traveling, and I'm struggling to get WOL to work from outside my home network.

I'm using an ASUS RT-AC68U router, which supports WOL via a web GUI served by the router. You can access the GUI via an IPv4 address (configured with DDNS), and all of that works great from inside my network. There's also a VPN feature which works great from inside my network.

However, my ISP (Webpass) is using a NAT that makes all local IPv4 addresses inaccessible from the internet. They do support IPv6, and I have successfully used Remote Desktop to log into the home computer from outside the network, but that only works when the computer is on. I haven't figured out how to resolve the web GUI, log into the VPN, or send WOL packets to the computer via IPv6. All seem like they would solve the issue, with WOL packets directly to the computer as the MVP.

Any suggestions would be appreciated. I'm happy to provide additional information, but I'm not sure what would be helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe the router just doesn't serve its GUI on IPv6. That would be strange, but not too surprising. That it serves the GUI to the WAN at all is worrying. Home router firmware is usually a steaming pile of crap. Consider replacing it with something like OpenWrt, which will let you do practically anything you want.

Answer (score 1):

Does your router allow you to forward UDP ports 7 and 9? You can try forwarding those to your LAN.

Comment: It's a solution. The OP can send WoL packets to his IPv6 address if his router forwards them, all will work out.

Comment: Right, WOL uses these ports! I made WOL some years ago, but then it went somehow differently (the MAC should existed 6 times in the packet sent, the port and an L3 level was not important). Okay, I removed the comment.

Comment: @peterh-ReinstateMonica ah sorry, it has been a while since I seriously engaged with wake on lan. The port itself is not supposed to be important to the working of the mechanism. The use of port 9 (discard all traffic) is just a custom. In theory wake on lan should work on any target port. 

Though the broadcast address could be important for some implementations. Some only listen for WoL packets on 255.255.255.255 (for ipv4), while some accept .255 on the last octet and anything else on the first 3.

Comment: My router does not support any port forwarding since the switch to IPv6. Any other solutions?

Comment: IPv6 doesn't have the concept of forwarding ports, as it doesn't use NAT

Comment: @Ferrybig   Nat6?

Comment: @BeigeTheColor Whoever proposed that should go straight to jail

Comment: @fjch1997 what are they going to do? Wake your machine up? Overflow the magic packet handling logic on the ethernet chip and own your pc?

Comment: @BeigeTheColor I was referring to NAT6